# Does this optocoupler circuit work practically?

Tags: mains, opto-isolator

I've been trying to make a circuit that:

1. Outputs 12V when the power is off
2. Outputs 0V when the power is on.

Input is 230V 50Hz AC.

I have a question about the voltage across the output capacitor. When the mains is on, it seems the average voltage across the capacitor is 0V. Am I correct or missing anything? I'd highly appreciate your input before going to mess with the high voltages...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fevH68.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Might not work as you intend (e.g. LED stays on if there is power, else off). If that's directly the mains, you may want to consider the heat, too.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen oh it's directly to the mains and R1=30kohm limits the current. Shouldn't it be fine?

Comment: You've drawn ground symbols on the "live" side and the "safe" (low voltage) side and as all symbols are the same, it means that they're connected. In reality you would not want that, I would remove the ground on the mains side (the left one) and only have ground on the safe part of the circuit.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Right! hadn't thought of that ty. Optocoupler output and capacitor just go tot he negative terminal of 12V supply. Then will it work? Can I go ahead and buy parts?

Comment: 230 V AC across **just one** resistor is "pushing it" as ordinary 1/4 resistors are rated for about 200 V. It is better to use two 15 k ohm resistors in series.

Comment: @across Suppose that LED can take full 325 V reverse voltage. The power dissipated by the resistor would be `~323^2 / 30k ~3.48 W`. You'll need at least some `5 W` rated resistor. If you want to prepare for the winter, that's fine. BTW, 1N4148 can only take 75 V (or 200?, can't remembrer).

Comment: There are "smarter" ways to make an LED (inside an optocoupler) light up more efficiently, search this site for "LED mains voltage" and you'll find some examples like the "capacitive dropper circuit".

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen good point. Can I replace 30k with four parallel 120k 1W resistors instead?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie do you mean replacing current limiting resistor with an appropriate capacitor ? That is using capacitive reactance to limit the current.. I'll google a bit more...

Comment: If nothing burns, will this circuit really output 12V when the mains is off and 0V when the mains is on? Does the logic part look okay to you? @Bimpelrekkie and aconcernedcitizen

Comment: The output is obviously 12V when the power is off. But when the power is on, I'm not so sure if the output stays 0V... @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: Also I'm not able to simulate this because circuitlab doesn't have optocoupler in the parts list

Comment: "When the mains is on, it seems the average voltage across the capacitor is 0V." - wasn't that the *whole point*? I thought you *wanted* 0V when the mains is on? What's the problem with that?

Comment: I know this isn't a direct answer, and I don't know your grand plan, but the simple answers are often overlooked: If you don't need constant cycling, you can do this all with a single relay, and it would even be sturdier against power surges.

Comment: @user253751 You're right. I want it to stay 0V when mains is on. Looks the average voltage is ~2V from the simulation, but I feel it is fine as it will not trigger the relay...

Answer (score 9):

This is pretty much fair, you just need a high power resistor.
[image: opto1]

The resistor can be replaced with a capacitor (220n 275VAC) and will not heat up.
[image: opto2]

Comment: May I know if R1 1k is required? It seems the 220n capacitor reactance limits the current, so... Thank you so much for the beautiful simulations:)

Comment: When first switched on, it is not known in which phase the capacitor is switched on. So the first charging current must be limited.

Comment: Indeed it must be limited, but isn't 1k a bit too small for that? I wouldn't risk exposing the LED to more than 100 mA even momentarily.

Comment: Forward surge current for the [LED](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81753/vo615a.pdf) 1,5A.

Answer (score 8):

Supposing the whole circuit works without smoke, what you have there is an optocoupler which will be turned on/off 50 times per second. This makes the transistor act the same. Which means that the cap will be charged according to the time constant, but discharged by the transistor. So there will be some voltage, but if you use a comparator afterwards, it should work.

**However**, the resistor will dissipate some 1.75 W (miscalculated in the comments), which means it will need a rating of at least 2 W (3 more likely). It might be best to listen to [Bimpelrekkie's suggestion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/518383/does-this-optocoupler-circuit-work-practically?noredirect=1#comment1330802_518383).

---

Here's a quick simulation in LTspice:

[image: test]

So if you want a relay afterwards, you could use it, since the voltage across the cap, even if not zero, will be, most probably, below the threshold. But be careful, even that little voltage as it is will still be considered a load by its inductance. Only don't connect the relay straight on the optocoupler's transistor, instead of  the 10k resistor, because you'll have an LC tank there.

Comment: interesting... so the average voltage on capacitor is not 0V! I'll be connecting the output to a *relay*. Do I still need a comparator or will I be okay?

Comment: @across I've updated my answer. I still say it's too crude a circuit, but it's your choice.

Comment: As you said, 50 times on/off cycle may cause in long term, some AC Input Optocouplers can help to improve circuit.